# Don't seem to be able to enable auditing for a custom dataverse table

Tags: dataverse

I've followed all the Microsoft directions, but still the auditing for my custom entity never stays checked as enabled.

I've enabled auditing for my environment, and my custom entity is working great... but although I can see a checkbox for enabling auditing for the table, I check it and save, and then it again shows as unchecked. When I look at a custom column, it tells me that "This column will not be audited until you enable auditing on the table."

I can even look at the Audit Summary for the environment, and it tells me that I've enabled Auditing.

UPDATE: after a couple of days, the enabling of audit for the environment has trickled down, and I can now successfully have auditing enabled for my dataverse entity. I hope this helps others!